# what is the event for product update

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, event-observer

I want to send an email when a product being changed.

I just need which event is used for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below event for save product after

```
catalog_product_save_after
```

Comment: It's for save a new product. Can it be used to update a product ?

Comment: event will be call on add new or update product.

Comment: Ya you are right.

Comment: accept my answer if solved your problem.